# no matching function for call to 'std::vector >::push_back(char&)'

Tags: c++, string, vector, stl, char

I have declared a string vector and also a string variable with some value. When I am trying to push back each character of my string variable to the string vector. I am getting an error as.
If I changed my string vector to a char vector then the code works fine.

Why is a string vector not taking characters in push_back() method ?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

int main() {
    vector<string> vec;
    string s = "hello";
    int len = vec.size();
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++) {
        vec.push_back(s[i]);
    }
}
```

error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector >::push_back(char&)'

```
Fix: vector<char> vec;
```

Comment: There is no `std::string` constructor which can take one `char`. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `vec.push_back(s[i));` brackets miss match.  I don't think you have posted the code the generated the error.  Also missing header file `<string>`.

Comment: I am trying to fill in a vector character by character from a string variable using the vector.push_back() method.

Comment: @Janet What's wrong with keeping them in `std::string`? Usually `std::string` is the best container for single characters. And if not that, why not `std::vector<char>`?

Comment: @RichardCritten Thanks for pointing out the typo, I had not imported string, but even after importing the error still exists.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Thank you for the response, I am new to STL and learning about vectors when I came across this error. So just trying to know why that error is happening.

Comment: @Janet "_So just trying to know why that error is happening._" It was already mentioned in the comments: `std::string` doesn't have any constructor, that accepts a single `char` as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you can't do this:

```
std::string('a');
```

Or this:

```
string s = "hello";
std::string(s[0]);
```

`std::string` doesn't have any constructor which would take a single `char`.

---

There are 3 options:

#### Keep your data in `std::string`

The easiest one. `std::string` is a container very alike to `std::vector`, except that it only stores `char` type.

#### Use `std::vector<char>`

If you need a vector rather than string, it's more reasonable to have a vector of single characters rather than vector of 1-char-long-strings.
You can initialize it either with

```
std::vector<char> vec(s.begin(), s.end())
```

or as you did in your try:

```
std::vector<char> vec;
std::string s = "hello";
for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++) {
    vec.push_back(s[i]);
}
```

#### Use `std::vector<std::string>`

If you really need to use vector of strings, you need to employ correct `std::string` constructor

```
std::vector<std::string> vec;
std::string s = "hello";
for(int i=0; i< s.length(); i++) {
    vec.push_back(std::string(1, s[i]));
}
```

Or a little more concise with [`std::vector::emplace_back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back)

```
std::vector<std::string> vec;
std::string s = "hello";
for(int i=0; i< s.length(); i++) {
    vec.emplace_back(1, s[i]);
}
```